# Setting a value of an iframe in the parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works on Chrome 58 but it makes me feel dirty:

```
parent.parent.parent.document.F1.document.getElementById("txtNewDrugAction").value = "foobar"
```

`F1` is the name of the `iFrame` where the text box resides.

I am setting the value of an input box from a modal popup window (via jQuery UI).  I've tried to use selectors etc, but to no avail.  I feel like there would be a hugely easier way to do this that would also be more resilient to changes in the DOM but I can't see it just yet...

I also wind up writing code like this (again, functional, but awful):

```
window.top.document.getElementById("F1").contentWindow.document.getElementById("txtRefresh") = "foobar"
```

I'm maintaining a legacy application. Please nobody think that something that uses frames is being created in 2017, especially not by me.

Comment: I'll agree that it "feels" dirty, and it surely is sensitive to changes in the DOM.

Comment: google maps, basically all the google plugins, facebook plugins etc.. lots of things are being developed in 2017 using iframes...

Comment: you forgot the `.value` in the last code snippet, so that will not function as is. also in that last snippet you can omit `window` unless there is another variable in scope called `top`.  `window` is global and therefore always in scope and therefore never needs to be stated.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to use `window.top` if `F1` is part of the top-most window, or possibly go top down `window.top.someframe.someotherframe.F1`.

An alternative might be to write a helper something like:

```
function getFrame(name) {
  var current = this;
  while (current) {
    if (current.document[name])
      return current.document[name].document;
    current = current.parent;
  }
  return undefined; // not found
}
```

Comment: Yeah the helper is a good idea.  How could I expand that to search through controls in that iframe as well?  I couldn't think of how, with document.all being deprecated.

Comment: You could use a second helper. iirc (as in, it's been a while since I messed around with this stuff) you could have your JS in `F1` create a method, say `window.setDrugAction(...)` then your code would be `getFrame('F1').setDrugAction('foobar')`. This would separate your responsibilities more cleanly.

Comment: there's no benefit to explicitly returning `undefined`. just `return;` by itself will return undefined, or you can omit the return entirely and the function will return undefined.

Comment: As far as the JS runtime is concerned you are right they are the same thing but if I am returning a specific value as a flag value I always put it in so that it is obvious to anyone reading the code what is happening. As a general rule I always return explicit values when defining a function that returns something.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get your problem so well but couldn't you interact with the parent via html5 postMessage call? Definite the protocol and then you're more decoupled from the DOM too.